# Git blame for staged files

Tags: git

Is there a way to do `git blame` on the staged (index) version of a file? The best I've been able to come up with is to extract the staged version to some temporary place and point `git blame --contents` at it. Is there a way to do it directly from the index?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no: `git blame` operates on commits (though it does, as you noted, start from the work-tree contents, or any content to which you point it).

It would, however, be trivial to make a commit *from* the index,<sup>1</sup> and tell `git blame` to start with the now-committed index contents as the first committed version:

```
git blame $(git commit-tree -p HEAD $(git write-tree) < /dev/null)
```

Change `HEAD` to whatever you like to make the temporary commit created here link back to whatever commit you like.

---

<sup>1</sup>Provided, of course, that the index is not in an unmerged state.